# Combine 1-row dataframe and n-rows dataframe, by duplicating the 1-row and append to n-rows dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider below dataframes, d1 as the student info and d2 as the subject grade

```
>>> data = [['Alice',18]]
>>> d1 = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
>>> d1
    Name  Age
0  Alice   18
>>> data2 = [['Science','A'],['Math','C'],['English','B']]
>>> d2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['Subject','Grade'])
>>> d2
   Subject Grade
0  Science     A
1     Math     C
2  English     B
```

I would like to combine d1 and d2 such that

```
    Name  Age  Subject Grade
0  Alice   18  Science     A
1  Alice   18     Math     C
2  Alice   18  English     B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use cross join with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) + [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) + [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) - this solution can be used if want combine multiple rows in `d1`:

```
df = pd.merge(d1.assign(A=1), d2.assign(A=1), on='A').drop('A', 1)
print (df)
    Name  Age  Subject Grade
0  Alice   18  Science     A
1  Alice   18     Math     C
2  Alice   18  English     B
```

Another solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = pd.concat([d1.reindex(d2.index, method='ffill'), d2], axis=1)
print (df)
    Name  Age  Subject Grade
0  Alice   18  Science     A
1  Alice   18     Math     C
2  Alice   18  English     B
```

Comment: Sure, my is different with reindex ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could do with `assign`

```
In [101]: d2.assign(**d1.iloc[0])
Out[101]:
   Subject Grade  Age   Name
0  Science     A   18  Alice
1     Math     C   18  Alice
2  English     B   18  Alice
```

Or,

```
In [102]: d2.assign(**d1.iloc[0].to_dict())
Out[102]:
   Subject Grade  Age   Name
0  Science     A   18  Alice
1     Math     C   18  Alice
2  English     B   18  Alice
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use concat with ffill i.e

```
ndf = pd.concat([d1,d2],1).ffill()
```

```
   Name   Age  Subject Grade
0  Alice  18.0  Science     A
1  Alice  18.0     Math     C
2  Alice  18.0  English     B
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not rebuild your `Dataframe`

```
pd.DataFrame([data[0]+x for x in data2],columns=['Name','Age','Subject', 'Grade'])
Out[279]: 
    Name  Age  Subject Grade
0  Alice   18  Science     A
1  Alice   18     Math     C
2  Alice   18  English     B
```